# Braising with 2 dutch ovens - time?

Tags: pork, cooking-time, slow-cooking, dutch-oven, braising

So, the wife and I are in charge of New Years dinner. That involves 2 5-lb boston butts.

One dutch oven is allclad, the other dutch oven is cast iron. The braising recipe calls for 8-10 hours on low in a slow cooker, or 4-5 hours at 325 in a dutch oven.

If we try to braise with both pots in the oven, how will that impact cooking time? Will it increase cooking time since we have 2 pots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no adjustments required: 
Yes, two pots take a few minutes longer to heat up than one, but with 4-5 hours total, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

No time adjustments **should** be required. I say should only because if your oven is not exactly at 325 it may take less or more time. Also the top shelf is warmer than the bottom and you may have to rotate the meats. The recipe may say 4-5 hours or until done. In cooking butts low and slow is what is recommended. I do mine on my Green Egg BBQ and also in the oven at 200 degrees but this will take 8 to 12 hours. At 275 8 hours. It is done when it is just over 200 degrees internal temp or when it is falling off the bone it is also done. Good luck have a great New Year!